# Stoke's Theorem Application on Cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, surface-integrals

This is a question regarding Stoke's theorem's application. This is in regards to a problem from MIT OCW.

My question is, referring to the [answer](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-93-example/MIT18_02SC_we_93_comb.pdf) provided, what **closed surfaces** are used in the proof for both 
$$ \oint_{C_1} \vec{F} \,dr , \oint_{C_2} \vec{F} \,dr $$

What does the curve $C_1 - C_2$ in
$$\oint_{C_1 - C_2} \vec{F} \,dr $$
even mean? How does Stoke's theorem apply here, and why does it mean the surface in between the two curves?

Answer (score 0):

In basic geometry you take by definition that (for $a,b$ numbers and $C,D$ curves):
$$
\int_{aC+bD}\omega\,dx := a\int_{C}\omega\,dx + b\int_{D}\omega\,dx.
$$

The motivation for this comes from algebraic topology.

So: 
$$
\oint_{C_1-C_2}F\,dr =\oint_{C_1}F\,dr - \oint_{C_2}F\,dr.
$$

You can think of the part $S$ of the cylinder between the two curves as "going" or "flowing" from $C_2$ to $C_1$, which in math means simply:
$$
C_2 + \partial S = C_1
$$
so that:
$$
\oint_{C_1-C_2}F\,dr =\oint_{\partial S}F\,dr.
$$

The surfaces are not closed! The curves are.